# Live Share Visual Studio Code Join or Share not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-liveshare

I can't join a live share session by the link given to me. It keeps loading or sometimes says RPC connection closed?

I have installed Live Share Extensions Pack as well as I am logged into github in VS Code. Please let me know if anyone needs more info

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue with the installation of libssl the following commands:

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libssl1.1
```

Comment: did not work for us on Ubuntu 20.04 TLS